# Javascript event listener not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

> If you come across this thread with a similar event listener problem the issue may be with your CSS and not your Javascript. See my answer below for details.

I've spent a considerable amount of time searching SO and looking at others' solutions to similar problems to no avail, so I've finally had to create an account.

I'm working on a webpage that has a picture of a world map with some location pins on top of it representing office locations. The idea is that mousing over one of this pins will alter some images and text elsewhere on the page.

However, when I mouseover any of the pins, nothing happens at all. No text or image changes elsewhere, and no messages printed to the console. I don't see any errors reported. I've made sure the events are not bound until after the document's ready, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. The console message "document ready" does get printed indicating the listeners should be bound. I've tried swapping in "click" to no effect, and I also tried using jQuery to delegate the event to the document (which was suggested in a similar question) and also saw no improvement.

Any help very much appreciated.

EDIT: Seeing some of the comments about clarity, I've commented out all of the code in my javascript except for what's listed below. I still don't see any console messages logged when I mouse over the element. Looking in the console, once more I don't see any error messages and I can verify the event "mouseenter" is in fact bound to meridianPin.

HTML for the map looks like this:

```
<!-- Image & Map Widgets -->
<div id="mapContainer" class="itt-contact-img-container">
  <img class="itt-full-width-image" src="./Images/mapBanner.png" alt="worldMap">
  <img id="bangalorePin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-bangalore" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="rosevillePin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-roseville" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="mumbaiPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-mumbai" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="jaipurPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-jaipur" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="lakeoswegoPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-lakeoswego" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="camasPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-camas" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="meridianPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-meridian" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
</div>
```

Commented out all event listener binding except for this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("document ready");
    document.getElementById("meridianPin").addEventListener("mouseenter", meridianHighlight);
})
```

Here's the highlight function in question now that everything else is commented out:

```
function meridianHighlight(){
  console.log("meridian highlight");

  $("#itt-contact-silhouette").attr("src","./Icons/svg/idaho.svg");

  $("#itt-contact-hdr-merdian").css("display","block");
  $("#itt-contact-info-merdian").css("display","block");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-camas").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-camas").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-lakeoswego").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-lakeoswego").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-roseville").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-roseville").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-jaipur").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-jaipur").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-mumbai").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-mumbai").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-bangalore").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-bangalore").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: When I try your code, I immediately get: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: camasHighlight is not defined"` We can't help you if we can't reproduce your issue, so you need to provide those other callback functions as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus _“And **each of my highlight functions** look essentially the same”_ implies that all of these functions are defined.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you doing things like  `document.getElementById("bangalorePin").addEventListener("mouseenter", bangaloreHighlight);`?

Comment: But, if there is a naming problem with any of them, it would prevent all the code from working.

Comment: @ScottMarcus He said he has the console open, so if there were an error like that he'd see it.

Comment: Can you check the HTML elements in the Inspector? In Firefox and Chrome they should have a little `ev` box next to them, indicating that they have some event listener bound to them. Click those and check whether the expected listeners are indeed bound.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, he said this and he said that. But, we don't know for sure. The code he did provide works, so logic would tell us that the problem must be with the code that wasn't provided.

Comment: odd how people would rather answer an unclear question to say there's nothing wrong rather than close as unclear or off topic until the question is clarified.

Comment: Also odd how people will down vote an answer that does its best to provide an answer. The question is not unclear, hence voting to close it as such is incorrect.

Comment: Neither answer is useful.

Comment: @KevinB Wrong. My answer shows that what was provided works and so, by process of elimination, tells the OP that the problem must be with the rest of the code. Debugging is often done by process of elimination.

Comment: and i find that to be no more useful as an answer than it is as a comment. you are free to have your own biased opinion on the matter.

Comment: @KevinB Comments can't include executable code. Hence, an answer was given. And, before you say just link to a Fiddle, 3rd party links can die over time and, if that happens, the comment won't make much sense.

Comment: No further executable code is needed if the code works as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was somehow a CSS problem. In my html you can see "mapBanner" at the top of the image group which was large image spanning the width of viewport, while each of the location icons was 22x22px. The icons appeared on top of the world map image on the page but took no notice of their mouseover event listeners. I changed the map picture to be the background image of the containing div, and now the event listeners fire as they should.

I'm happy to know how to move forward but I still don't understand how what I did earlier was wrong (aside from it not working), should I expect page large elements to mask the event listeners of smaller elements within?

Comment: look up z-index property with css, it allows you to bring forward/layer elements.

Comment: @user379842 I was actually using the z-index property, I assigned my background image a z-index of -1 and my location pins a z-index of 10, and they did appear on top of the map like I intended. I noticed once I took the large image out of the div it collapsed to a height of zero, I suppose that must have had something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided all the callback functions, so we can't know what the exact issue is, but the one that you did provide is firing as it should, so I'm inclined to believe you have some syntax errors in the remaining code that is preventing all the code from running.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("document ready");
    document.getElementById("meridianPin").addEventListener("mouseenter", meridianHighlight);

})

function meridianHighlight(){
  console.log("meridian highlight");

  $("#itt-contact-silhouette").attr("src","./Icons/svg/idaho.svg");

  $("#itt-contact-hdr-merdian").css("display","block");
  $("#itt-contact-info-merdian").css("display","block");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-camas").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-camas").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-lakeoswego").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-lakeoswego").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-roseville").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-roseville").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-jaipur").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-jaipur").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-mumbai").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-mumbai").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-hdr-bangalore").css("display","none");
  $("#itt-contact-info-bangalore").css("display","none");
}
```

```css
#meridianPin {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Image & Map Widgets -->
<div id="mapContainer" class="itt-contact-img-container">
  <img class="itt-full-width-image" src="./Images/mapBanner.png" alt="worldMap">
  <img id="bangalorePin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-bangalore" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="rosevillePin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-roseville" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="mumbaiPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-mumbai" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="jaipurPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-jaipur" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="lakeoswegoPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-lakeoswego" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="camasPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-camas" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
  <img id="meridianPin" class="itt-contact-pin itt-contact-pin-meridian" src="./Icons/svg/locationIcon.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Lol, didn't see your post before posting mine. My bad!

Comment: The down vote was unwarranted. I am showing the the code does work and I am providing a best-guess answer.